# Python Selenium hover on youtube next button

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, youtube

I am new in this domain, I just want to make a script who can download all my songs from youtube playlist (by taking the url and convert it in another website). I am using Python - Selenium.

The problem is that I can't hover on the video menu bar to acces the "next" button. I've seen some tutorials on internet but it didn't work. I don't know exactly how to reach that hover area.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share your code trials and the relevant HTML?